# Return records of groupby with a count of one

Tags: sql

I have two tables `user_expenses` and `users`.

The foreign key for `user_expenses` is `user_expenses.user_id` which corresponds to `users.id`.

I would like to get some information from both tables, in which the users have only ONE expense.

I gave this a shot:

```
SELECT 
    users.id, users.email, users.stripe_plan, users.previous_plan, 
    users.created_at, user_expenses.created_at, user_expenses.description
FROM 
    users
INNER JOIN 
    user_expenses ON user_expenses.user_id = users.id
WHERE 
    user_expenses.description NOT LIKE "%free%"
GROUP BY 
    user_expenses.user_id
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) = 1
```

But of course, this yields the following problem:

> SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'app.user_expenses.created_at' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Adding this column into the `group_by` is problematic because it will actually return users who have multiple expenses with different descriptions.

Can anyone offer some advice on how to approach this problem? I only want users with a single entry in the `user_expenses` table, regardless of the type of description.

Comment: What database client are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a dummy aggregation. Change:

```
user_expenses.created_at, user_expenses.description
```

in the `select` list by:

```
min(user_expenses.created_at) created_at, min(user_expenses.description) description
```

... which will be the same as the original value, since you know you only have one per group.

It would also be more natural to group by the `users.id` field, which has as advantage that it allows for outer joining the `user_expenses` table (if ever you would need that):

```
group by users.id
```

NB: in MySql 5.7+ it is not necessary to aggregate fields that are [functionally dependent on the grouped-by fields](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). Since all fields of the `users` record are determined by the `users.id` value they can go without aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

You could do either a subquery or you could pseudo-aggregate values that are not in the group by list:

(1):

```
SELECT users.id, users.email, users.stripe_plan, users.previous_plan, users.created_at, user_expenses.created_at, user_expenses.description
FROM users
INNER JOIN user_expenses
ON user_expenses.user_id = users.id
WHERE user_expenses.description NOT LIKE "%free%"
and users.id not in
  (select ue2.user_id from user_expenses ue2 group by user_id having count(*) > 1)
```

(2)

```
SELECT users.id, max(users.email), max(users.stripe_plan), max(users.previous_plan), max(users.created_at), max(user_expenses.created_at), max(user_expenses.description)
FROM users
INNER JOIN user_expenses
ON user_expenses.user_id = users.id
WHERE user_expenses.description NOT LIKE "%free%"
GROUP BY user_expenses.user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```